# Why do I get negative expectationvalues when I use ladder operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I'm trying to find the expectationvalue for $p^2$ where $p = i\sqrt{\frac{hmw}{2}}(a_{+} - a_{-})$ and i end up with the following result
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi_0|p^2|\psi_0\rangle &= -\frac{\hbar mw}{2}\langle\psi_0|(a_{+} - a_{-})^2|\psi_0\rangle\\
&= -\frac{\hbar mw}{2}\langle\psi_0|a_{+}^2 - a_{+}a_{-} - a_{-}a_{+} + (a_{-})^2|\psi_0\rangle\\
\Rightarrow \langle\psi_0|p^2|\psi_0\rangle &= -\frac{\hbar mw}{2}(\langle\psi_0|a_{+}^2|\psi_0\rangle -\langle\psi_0|a_{-}a_{+}|\psi_0\rangle)\\
&= -\frac{\hbar mw}{2}(\langle a_{+}\psi_0|a_{+}\psi_0\rangle - \langle a_{-}\psi_0|a_{+}\psi_0\rangle)\\
&= -\frac{\hbar mw}{2}(\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle - \langle0|0\rangle)\\
&= -\frac{\hbar m w}{2}
\end{align*}
Where i've used the fact that $a_{+}a_{-}\psi_0 = 0$ and $a_{-}a_{+}\psi_0 = \psi_0$. I can see that the minus sign appears because to the imaginary number, but i must be missing something because the result is not supposed to be negative.

Comment: I see now that i made another mistake when it comes to $\langle \psi_0|a_{-}a_{+}|\psi_0\rangle$ which $\neq 0$. It's quite an odd mistake because i stated that i used the fact that $a_{-}a_{+}\psi_0 = \psi_0$.

Comment: Third line is wrong.

Comment: Why? I don't see it. @DanielSank

Comment: Ooops, I was wrong. Forget it.

Comment: By the way, the easy way to do this is use $[a_-, a_+] = 1$. Then $\langle 0 | a_- a_+ | 0 \rangle = \langle | a_+ a_- | 0 \rangle + \langle 0 | 0 \rangle = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that 
$$
\langle 0|\hat{a}^{\dagger} \neq \langle 1 |
$$
In fact,
$$
\langle 0 |\hat{a}^{\dagger} = (\hat{a}|0\rangle)^{\dagger} = 0
$$

Comment: Thanks! I also made a quite embarrassing mistake in the other term.